# wxgrid , Detecting Scroll event

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have created a wxGrid with custom table. Whenever the user scrolls down to very bottom of the grid, I have to load the next 100 rows from my table. I tried EVT_SCROLL_BOTTOM() but I am not able to detect it. What is the right thing to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question but I am reminded that the grid was designed to work with an object of type [wxGridTableBase](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxgridtablebase.html)  that can be extended by the application.  By extending this class, you should be able to do whatever caching you want inside of the extended object.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the scroll win event for the grid. I have encountered almost the same requirement as you. :)

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.OnScroll)
```